# Create row header using table view Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an array of an array of strings
At top level:

```
 Array = [[November 1 2016], [November 2 2016], [November 3 2016, ..., [Current    Date]]
```

In array [November 1 2016], it contains a strings [timeOne, timeTwo, timeThree...]. Similar strings occur under the array [November 2 2016] and on.

The goal is to create a table that has a row showing the date as shown in the top level array, for example "November 1 2016". And then under that top row have all the values (timeOne, timeTwo etc.) from that arrow in individual cells.
For example

```
 Row 1 = November 1 2016
 Row 2 = timeOne
 Row 3 = timeTwo
 Row 4 = timeThree
 Row 5 = November 2 2016
```

I have a function that creates an Array of the "timeOne, timeTwo, timeThree..." and then I can add that to the appropriate array.
The problem with my method of creating an array inside an array is that multiple timeValues will be taken each day.
How can I get swift to only record the date once each day the app is used and create a new array for this day. (for example if app not opened November 3, then the array includes November 2, November 4. But skips November 3.

Essentially what I am after is a table that looks kind of like this, but with only one column. Where it says 7:00am, 8:00am etc. will be my timeOne and timeTwo respectively

Is there a better way of going about this?
[image: End goal from UI tableview]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to utilise the `sections` functionality of `UITableView`. In your case, each date would be it's own section, with the times subsequently being rows.

For example you could do something like the following:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 20))
    label.text = dates[section] // Would set to the date in the array.
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` iterate through the times and display those.

If you need me to elaborate on anything just say.

**EDIT:**

A very crude implementation would look a little like this, obviously you'll need to populate the date and time array values.

```
class Time {
    var timeString: String!
    var eventString: String!
}

class Date {
    var dateString: String!
    var times: [Time]!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var dates = [Date]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = dates[indexPath.section].times[indexPath.row].timeString
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dates.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dates[section].times.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 20))
        label.text = dates[section].dateString
        return label
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I think this is what I am after. However, when I am creating each timeValue. I am also creating a date. how do I have multiple timeValues taking during one day, correspond to one section header. And how to I make each section header dynamically update to the day that the below values were taken

Comment: See amended answer.